# Mi programa continua ejecutándose y abriendo archivos sin parar

Tags: python

Quiero obtener el negativo de una imagen que ya esta a escala de grises, pero al presionar "ejecutar" el programa me trae la imagen sin el efecto negativo y continua cargando mas imágenes hasta que se satura la memoria y me muestra un error, este es mi código:

```py
from PIL import Image
import time
import numpy as np

def negativo_grises(im):
    tiempoIn = time.time()
    ruta = ("C:/Users/Francisco/Pictures/" + im)
    im = Image.open(ruta)
    im.show() 
    im6 = im
    i = 0
    while i < im6.size[0]:
        j = 0
        while j < im6.size[1]:
            gris = im6.getpixel((i,j))
            valor = 255 - gris
            im6.putpixel((i,j), valor)
            j += 1
            i += 1
            im6.show()
            tiempoFin = time.time()
    print("El proceso tardo: ", tiempoFin - tiempoIn, "segundos")
```

Comment: nunca modificas `i` y comparas siempre con el elemento `0` en el array im6.size. Ciertamente se va a ejecutar hasta el fin de los tiempos.

Comment: Estás tratando de mostrar la imagen por cada cambio de píxel, intenta sacando el segundo `im6.show()` y ponerlo despúes de ambos bucles (fuera de los `while`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te decía en los comentarios, tu problema principal es que estás mostrando la imagen por cada posición del píxel en `(i, j)`. Si tu imagen tiene un tamaño de 1000x1000 entonces estarías abriendo 1,000,000 de imágenes.

Aunque, ahora que veo, me sorprende que siquiera funcione, ya que hay algunos errores en tu código. Basicamente debería fallar en esta línea:

```
valor = 255 - gris
```

Ya que `gris` debe contener una tupla (cada píxel es una combinación de RGB). Lo más sencillo, en vez de usar `while`s, es iterar usando `for`s con el tamaño de la imagen:

```
from PIL import Image


def negativo(ruta):
    im = Image.open(ruta)
    im.show()
    for i in range(im.size[0]):
        for j in range(im.size[1]):
            r, g, b = im.getpixel((i, j)) # Rojo, verde y azul
            nr, ng, nb = (255 - r, 255  - g, 255 - b) # Invertimos cada color
            im.putpixel((i, j), (nr, ng, nb)) # Reemplazamos el pixel con los colores invertidos
    im.show()
```

Observa que `r`, `g` y `b` contiene los colores rojo, verde y azul para el píxel en la posición `(i, j)`, luego para cada uno de ellos se crea el negativo restando 255 a sus valores.

Si yo hago la prueba con una captura de pantalla que tengo localmente, esto es lo que me muestran los dos `im.show()` (el original y el negativo):

```
negativo("Selection_424.png")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Existe una forma más fácil de invertir los colores con PIL usando [`ImageOps`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.invert):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps


def negativo(ruta):
    im = Image.open(ruta)
    im.show()
    negative = ImageOps.invert(im)
    negative.show()
```

Comment: Sin querer me ayudaste igualmente con otro problema acerca de una tupla en otro código, muchas gracias!